# How to check if json contains another json using jq?

Tags: json, bash, shell, jq

I have just started using jq and I need to check if a given json is present in another json using jq?

Suppose this is my `json_input`:

```
{
  "info": {
    "values": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "val"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to check if the above json input is present inside the following `available_json`:

```
{
  "info": {
    "values": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "val"
          },
          {
            "name": "name2",
            "value": "val2"
          },
          {
            "name": "name3",
            "value": "val3"
          }
        ],
        "key1":"val1",
        "key2":"val2"
      }
    ],
    "priority":1,
    "objects":[
      {
        "name":"a"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Both json are stored in variables and should report the presence for any `json_input` given as input based on any `available_json` (generic). How can this be done using jq?

Or Is there any other better way like converting both json to string and then comparing?

PS: The json object key `info` is fixed and the `values` can change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is so trivial that one might not even think of it: Using the jq filter [contains](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#contains(element)):

```
jq 'contains({
  "info": {
    "values": [
      {
        "data": [
          {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "val"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})' available.json
```

Output will be `true` or `false`. If you run `jq -e` (`--exit-status`), it will set the exit status accordingly, which allows you to use it together with `if` or `&&`/`||` in your shell.

If you the `input_json` is also stored in a file:

```
jq --slurpfile input_json input_json 'contains($input_json[0])' available.json
```

If the JSON document is stored in a variable, then `--argjson` instead of `--slurpfile`:

```
jq --argjson input_json "$input_json" 'contains($input_json)' available.json
```

or simply relying on parameter expansion of your shell:

```
jq "contains($input_json)" available.json
```